# Remove copy right text from child theme of alpha-store theme template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a child theme from alpha-store theme template. I need to remove the copy right text without modifying the core theme

```
<?php 
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
 function my_theme_enqueue_styles() { 
      wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' ); 
      } 




     add_action('tha_footer_top', 'your_function');

function your_function() {
  $content = '<div class="site-info container"><p>This is inserted at the bottom</p></div>';
  echo $content;
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried `remove_action` ?

Comment: i tried this and not work function remove_the_footer_entirely( $creds ) {
return '';
}
add_filter('alpha-store_footer_creds_text', 'remove_the_footer_entirely');

Comment: paste website link here? so css will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove the whole element from the child theme unless you replace the whole footer.php file in the child.

The one thing you can do though is use css to hide the element from view in the child theme.

You could then insert your own text using the action.

For example :

```
.site-info{
    display:none;
}
```

And then you could insert your own text like this in your functions.php file in the child theme.

```
 add_action('tha_footer_top', 'new_function');

function new_function() {
  $content = '<div class="new-text container"><p>This the new text to 
              be added in</p></div>';
  echo $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`remove_action`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) to stop displaying the copyright notice.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'so_45559746_remove_copyright' );

function so_45559746_remove_copyright(){
    remove_action( 'tha_footer_top', 'your_function' );
}
```

Hiding the copyright text with CSS [*may* result in unfavourable SEO rankings](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353?hl=en).